# Change the user role based on login or theme switch

Tags: user-roles, switch-theme

I'm developing a CMS system based on a multisite installation.  I need to be able to do the following:

1. Whenever a user logs into his site, he will immediately be forced into "Contributor" role.  I will add the privilege of theme selection to this role, so he will be able to change the site theme.
2. When the user executes a theme change, he needs to be put into "Admin" role -- because I am going to be executing some other code (e.g. page deletions and page creations) hooked into the theme change event.  He will need Admin authority temporarily, for those actions to work.
3. Once the new theme has been selected, he will have to be placed back into "Contributor" role.

I believe I understand how to do this via appropriate API calls.  What I am struggling with is *where* to do it.  Questions:

1. Where do you hook code into "when a user logs in"?
2. I want to handle the "change the role to Admin when a theme switch is initiated" and "change the role back once new theme is done being selected" pieces via plugin (I do *not* want to mess with the theme logic) - I'm confused as to how to construct the plugin so it responds when those events occur.

Thanks for any pointers you can give.

Comment: If you are programmatically executing functions like edit/delete post, the current user doesn't need to have any particular permissions - it's up to you to check & implement. In other words, I'm just making sure that you *definitely* need to temporarily elevate user permissions and that we don't have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) on our hands.

Comment: ahhh...great point, thank you.  I had assumed that when programmatically executing something outside the current user's permission scope - the system would disallow the action.  If I can make the API call to delete pages (for example) even though the user doesn't have any edit permission for pages...and it will work...then you have just solved the real question I should have asked.

Comment: All core functions do not implement permissions checking - otherwise think of the chaos it would cause! For example, when editing a post in the admin, WordPress makes all the checks in a "controller", which then execute the action-related functions only if the user has appropriate permissions.